# using RowFilter without clearing it

Tags: vb.net, filter, row

I have a `DataTable` as follows

```
ID  Name    Type
1   Ram     Employee
2   John    Supplier
3   Uma     Employee
1   Ravi    Supplier
```

I assigned it to `PartyDV`. I am using the `RowFilter` as

```
PartyDV.RowFilter = "Type = 'Supplier'"
```

after that I am using the `RowFilter` in the same DV. In this I am not clearing the `RowFilter`.

```
PartyDV.RowFilter = "ID = 1"
```

what will be my answer

```
A)
ID  Name    Type
1   Ravi    Supplier
B)      
ID  Name    Type
1   Ram     Employee
1   Ravi    Supplier
```

A or B?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your questions!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your answer will be "B" but you could have figured that out yourself by running the code!

Basically when you execute the following lines of code:

```
 PartyDV.RowFilter = "Type = 'Supplier'"
 PartyDV.RowFilter = "ID = 1"
```

The second will override the first. They don't *add up*.

If you wanted to use both filters you may try this:

```
 PartyDV.RowFilter = "Type = 'Supplier' AND ID = 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course your answer would be B, cause even you aren't clearing the filter, but the program will clear by itself. I have ever made thing like this. It just like your answer B. If you want your answer to be A. You must having two filter at a time.

like this (just like what @Milky Dinescu) answer

```
PartyDV.RowFilter = "Type = 'Supplier' AND ID = 1"
```

Of course you can't divide them just as your question. Cause it will be same result.
Logic thinking :
Just like you write

```
textbox1.text = "first" 'it will be first as value
textbox1.text = "Second" 'it will be second as value, first will be delete
if you want to combine, you must like this isn't it?
textbox1.text = "First" & "Second"
```

So, it's the same logic as filter